Can anyone explain these Schlafli symbol notations? $sr\{2,5/2\}$, $s\{2,10/3\}$, $sr\{2,5/3\}$
Looking for help from a Geometry expert.  I am doing research on various polyhedra and would greatly appreciate a thorough explanation of why the following shapes have the Schlafli symbols they do (according to wikipedia, anyway), along with the Schlafli symbol for the third shape.  What do the s and sr mean?

(For example, "The Schlafli Symbol for a small stellated dodecahedron is $\{\color{red}{\frac{5}{2}}, \color{limegreen}{5}\}$ because each face is a pentagram with $\color{red}{5}$ vertices where each edge skips to every $\color{red}{2}$nd vertex, and there are $\color{limegreen}{5}$ pentagrams that meet at every vertex of the polyhedron".)

I don't recommend that notation, partly because ${2,n}$ is degenerate. Instead I'd just call them ${n}$ antiprisms (with $n=\tfrac52,\tfrac53,\tfrac74$, respectively).

{P,Q} = x-P-o-Q-o is the regular polyhedron with P-gonal faces, Q at each vertex.
Prefix operators to Schläfli symbols are not standard. However in here they can be reverse engineered from the additionally shown pics:
Then r{P,Q} = o-P-x-Q-o should be the rectified polyhedron, starting from {P,Q}. It is the uniform polyhedron made from alternatingly placed P-gons and Q-gons, 2 of each per vertex.
And s (as an operator symbol) seems to be the snub operator in its Johnson reading, i.e. the hemiation applied after the truncate operator t.
I.e. t{P,Q} = x-P-x-Q-o, tr{P,Q} = t(r{P,Q}) = x-P-x-Q-x, and thus s{P,Q} = s-P-s-Q-o, sr{P,Q} = s-P-s-Q-s.
Here t{P,Q} = x-P-x-Q-o is the truncated {P,Q}, i.e. being built from (2P)-gons and Q-gons with two (2P)-gons and one Q-gon per vertex. While tr{P,Q} = t(r{P,Q}) = x-P-x-Q-x rather is the omnitruncated {P,Q}, i.e. having (2P)-gons, (2Q)-gons as well as squares for faces, one of each per vertex, which come alternatingly in a right-handed and a left-handed version.
The finally searched for s{P,Q} = s-P-s-Q-o and sr{P,Q} = s-P-s-Q-s are the respective vertex alternations thereof (or, to be more precise, are "used" to describe the all unit-edged variants thereof). I.e. the former only applies for even Q=2q, being built from P-gons, q-gons (if q>2), and several "snub-face" triangles. The vertex cycle here is [3,P,3,P,3,q] (where the latter q just is to be neglected if Q=2q=4). Within the above picture example it applies to s2s10/3o or s2s14/4o, having two (P=2)-gons (which are to be neglected), one q=Q/2=(10/3)/2=5/3-gram (retrograde pentagrams) and 3 triangles per vertex in the first case, respectively two (P=2)-gons (which are to be neglected), one q=Q/2=(14/2)/4=7/4-gram (retrograde great heptagrams) and 3 triangles per vertex in the second case. - It shall be noted here that "n/d" in {n/d} is NOT a fraction, it rather is a shorthand description of "n vertices, but connecting every d-th one only". "d" is also known as the density of that polygram.
The latter sr{P,Q} = s-P-s-Q-s on the other hand applies for any P and Q and has faces being P-gons, Q-gons, and several "snub-face" triangles. The vertex cycle here is [3,P,3,Q,3]. (Convex examples of the latter are the well-known "snub cube" s3s4s and the "snub dodecahedron" s3s5s.) In the above small picture series this type applies to all:

sr{2,5/2} = s2s5/2s having (P=2)-gons (to be neglected), (prograde) (Q=5/2)-grams, and triangles; it is the "pentagrammic antiprism".
sr{2,5/3} = s2s5/3s having (P=2)-gons (to be neglected), retrograde (Q=5/3)-grams, and triangles; it is the "pentagrammic retroprism" (or "retrograde pentagrammic antiprism")
sr{2,7/4} = s2s7/4s having (P=2)-gons (to be neglected), retrograde (Q=7/4)-grams, and triangles; it is the "great heptagrammic retroprism" (or "retrograde great heptagrammic antiprism"); here "great heptagramm" applies to {7/3} (whereas "small heptagramm" would apply to {7/2} instead)

(Within the Stott-Coxeter-Dynkin diagrams o-nodes mean non-ringed nodes, x-nodes mean ringed nodes, and s-nodes represent the secondary process of alternation applied to the very same diagram, where all s-nodes get replaced by x-nodes (which serves as starting figure), and alternation applies to those sub-elements, which are represented by the sub-diagram, where all s-nodes and adjacent links get omitted. Eg. s4o3x starts with x4o3x and alternates thereon the . o3x, in keeping those or replacing them by their sectioning facets underneath. - Cf. "Snubs, Alternated Facetings, & Stott-Coxeter-Dynkin Diagrams", published at: Symmetry: Culture and Science, Vol. 21, No.4, 329-344, 2010)
--- rk
